# Visual Studio Code default namespace

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I create a file within a project in Visual Studio Code, it generates `namespace folder_name` automatically. How would I get all files I create within that project to generate `namespace solution_name.folder_name` automatically?

I tried setting the `<RootNamespace>` in the csproj file and that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[you can use [Add folder to workspace]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbumN.jpg)